# Sitecore 9 Update 1 Web.Config MachineToApplication error after installation

Tags: iis, web-config, sitecore

Fresh from the installation process (SIF) several lines in the site web.config produce the following error:

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 211:      </namespaces>
Line 212:    </pages>
Line 213:    <membership defaultProvider="sitecore" 
hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
Line 214:      <providers>
Line 215:        <clear />
```

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp0.sc\web.config    Line: 213

The installation process seems to have created the application directory fine, and it is marked as an application. There is no web.config in a directory higher than the site root. The Sitecore developer forums are offline, so I can't get help from there. This is on Windows 10 Pro, IIS 10.

I have tried the solutions suggested by other posts for similar IIS errors. There is no obj directory to delete, there is no debug build. This is straight from the Sitecore installation process.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your Feature Delegation settings for ".NET Users"? IIS Manager -> Feature Delegation -> ".NET Users" should be "Configuration Read/Write".

Comment: Thank you for that. I just checked, and it is set to Configuration Read/Write.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. I had to move the application directory as installed up to the root of the web site, mark it as an application again, and open up the directory security so that the files were all accessible. It was an undocumented additional set of steps needed to get things working on my Windows 10 Pro development machine. I have not tried xconnect, which is also in a subdirectory.

Comment: Its unbelievable how picky it all is. For my sitecore site  physical path I got this error because I had put C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteCoreApplication instead of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteCoreApplication\Website Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error after a fresh install of 9.0.2. It turns out the issue was that I was using "http://localhost/xp0.sc" to access the site. When I used "http://xp0.sc", I was able to load the site.

The first URL is attempting to load the site within the context of the Default web application, which is causing the web.config override error.